# set fileUrl and networkurl for Fresco SimpleDraweeView

Tags: xml, fresco

Is it possible to set the URI ( fileuri or networkUri ) i want to load into the view.

I don't see this in the documentation.
it has for retry, error and manyother bit not the actual uri, am i missing anything?

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
fresco:fadeDuration="300"
fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
fresco:placeholderImage="@color/wait_color"
fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
fresco:failureImage="@drawable/error"
fresco:failureImageScaleType="centerInside"
fresco:retryImage="@drawable/retrying"
fresco:retryImageScaleType="centerCrop"
fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/progress_bar"
fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"
fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
fresco:backgroundImage="@color/blue"
fresco:overlayImage="@drawable/watermark"
fresco:pressedStateOverlayImage="@color/red"
fresco:roundAsCircle="false"
fresco:roundedCornerRadius="1dp"
fresco:roundTopLeft="true"
fresco:roundTopRight="false"
fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
fresco:roundBottomRight="true"
fresco:roundWithOverlayColor="@color/corner_color"
fresco:roundingBorderWidth="2dp"
fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/border_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load it with the actualImageUri property:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
fresco:actualImageUri="https://your.url" />
```

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/a5456ad2cdb9214ebefaf11128d18e1c9edc7784/drawee/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L146